# Issue with Java web crawler using jsoup

Tags: java, web, web-crawler, cumulative-sum

I am having issues getting my web crawler class to work for my java class project. Here is the prompt:

In this project, you are to create a web crawler class.

Two notes before we discuss what to do with the class:

Make sure that you sleep for at least 0.5 seconds between hitting each link. This is to make sure that you do not ultimately DDOS any site that you wish to crawl. To get your program to sleep, check out this documentation from oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html (Links to an external site.)
For the sake of not traversing advertisement sites, we will be using wikipedia links.

This class needs to do two things:

Have a function that traverses 1000 links.
Have a function that counts words, that is, every time you see a specific word, increment a number associated with that word. (Hint: Sets may be a good option for this). Note: Your function should count words, not html elements / attributes.

I do not necessarily care how you implement this project so long as you have a class that, at the end of your 1000 link traversal your class:

- prints out the title of each page you've traversed
- prints out a list of words encountered. Again, html elements / attributes should not be in this list (i.e. no '

  ' or ''s should be in your list).

---

This is the code I have so far, not exactly sure what am i doing wrong? It gets all kinds of errors (examples below) right off the bat that have to do with datatypes, but I thought I had it all correct. Haven't had luck researching as I am very new to programming.

//crawler.java

```
package edu.umsl

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class crawler {
    // define max number of pages to visit
    private static final int MAX_PAGES = 1000;
    // collect all titles
    private HashSet<String> titles = new HashSet<>();
    // keep track of url visited
    private HashSet<String> urlVisited = new HashSet<>();
    // keep track of words and count
    private HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    // recursive function to crawl web
    public void getLinks(String startURL) {
        // condition to end the recursion
        if ((titles.size() < MAX_PAGES) && !urlVisited.contains(startURL)) {
            // add new url to set
            urlVisited.add(startURL);
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(startURL).get();
                Elements linksFromPage = doc.select("a[href]");
                // take all text to count words
                String title = doc.select("title").first().text();
                titles.add(title);
                String text = doc.body().text();
                CountWords(text);
                for (Element link : linksFromPage) {
                    if (titles.size() <= MAX_PAGES) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        getLinks(link.attr("abs:href"));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("URL couldnt visit");
                        System.out.println(startURL + ", " + urlVisited.size());
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
//           catch (InterruptedException e) {
//               e.printStackTrace();
//           }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // method to print all titles
    public void PrintAllTitles() {
        for (String t : titles) {
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    }

    // method to print word and count
    public void PrintAllWordsAndCount() {
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key + " : " + map.get(key));
        }
    }

    private void CountWords(String text) {
        String[] lines = text.split(" ");
        for (String word : lines) {
            if (map.containsKey(word)) {
                int val = map.get(word);
                val += 1;
                map.remove(word);
                map.put(word, val);
            } else {
                map.put(word, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//driver.java

```
package edu.umsl


public class driver {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
  
       crawler c = new crawler();
       c.getLinks("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science");
       System.out.println("*******************************Printing all titles*******************************");
       c.PrintAllTitles();
       System.out.println("*******************************Printing all Words*******************************");
       c.PrintAllWordsAndCount();
   }

}
```

Here is the first error that i get. all of the other errors are the same, with additional repetitions of the line:
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)

```
org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException: Unhandled content type. Must be text/*, application/xml, or application/*+xml. Mimetype=image/svg+xml, URL=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/People_icon.svg
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:772)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:707)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:297)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:286)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:33)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
at edu.umsl.Driver.main(Driver.java:8)
```

UPDATE: I had the attribute key in link.atr as "abs:href" instead of "a[href]"

This solved the error issue! Thanks!

Comment: `"...what am i doing wrong? It gets all kinds of errors..."` -- start by telling and showing the exact error messages. These messages shouldn't be ignored as they usually hold the key to your problem

Comment: I apologize, first time new user here! I added an example of the error message..

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I had the attribute key in link.atr as "abs:href" instead of "a[href]"

This solved the error issue! Thanks!

This occurred in line 50 of Crawler.java

updated code:

//Crawler.java

```
package edu.umsl;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Crawler {

    // define max number of pages to visit
    private static final int MAX_PAGES = 1000;
    // collect all titles
    private HashSet<String> titles = new HashSet<>();
    // keep track of url visited
    private HashSet<String> urlVisited = new HashSet<>();
    // keep track of words and count
    private HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    // recursive function to crawl web
    public void getLinks(String startURL) {

        // condition to end the recursion
        if ((titles.size() < MAX_PAGES) && !urlVisited.contains(startURL)) {

            //add new url to set
            urlVisited.add(startURL);

            try {

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(startURL).get();
                Elements linksFromPage = doc.select("a[href]");

                // take all text to count words
                String title = doc.select("title").first().text();

                titles.add(title);
                String text = doc.body().text();

                CountWords(text);

                for (Element link : linksFromPage) {

                    if(titles.size() <= MAX_PAGES) {

                        //sleep 1 sec before hitting another link. uncomment this to wait for a sec
                        //Thread.sleep(1000);
                        getLinks(link.attr("a[href]"));
                     }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("URL couldnt visit");
                        System.out.println(startURL + ", " + urlVisited.size());
                    }

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
//           catch (InterruptedException e) {
//
//               e.printStackTrace();
//
//           }
            catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    //method to print all titles
    public void PrintAllTitles() {

        for (String t : titles) {
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    }

    //method to print word and count
    public void PrintAllWordsAndCount() {

        for (String key : map.keySet()) {

            System.out.println(key + " : " + map.get(key));
        }
    }

    private void CountWords(String text) {

        String[] lines = text.split(" ");

        for (String word : lines) {

            if (map.containsKey(word)) {
                int val = map.get(word);
                val += 1;
                map.remove(word);
                map.put(word, val);
            } else {
                map.put(word, 1);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Now my issue is that it only traverses one link and it still counts some HTML elements and attributes i wanted to ignore. It also completes the program, but with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must supply a valid URL
    at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.notEmpty(Validate.java:102)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:127)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:70)
    at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)
    at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:33)
    at edu.umsl.Crawler.getLinks(Crawler.java:50)
    at edu.umsl.Driver.main(Driver.java:8)
*******************************Printing all titles*******************************
Science - Wikipedia
*******************************Printing all Words*******************************
half : 6
21–73. : 1
Western : 15
diverges : 1
Sheet". : 1
ten : 1
sake : 1
Robbins, : 1
energy : 4
Engineering". : 1
(SCAMs): : 1
" : 1
p.3—Lindberg, : 1
Fleck,] : 1
BCE : 3
& : 12
) : 1
require : 2
Harold; : 1
- : 1
completion, : 1
Strauss : 2
/ : 3
1 : 4
2 : 3
3 : 4
4 : 2
5 : 2
6 : 1
7 : 4
8 : 1
9 : 1
: : 3
A : 26
role : 7
G : 1
1000 : 1
Widespread : 1
H : 2
Abi : 1
I : 4
K : 1
O : 1
result : 2
R : 2
same : 7
Lightman, : 1
(1932) : 1
```